# iTextSharp not working in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have 2 pieces of code. The first one is working, second one is inside a loop and it doesn't show the value.

Anyone have any idea? Could it be looping is too fast for `memorystream` to read?

I am writing everything to a `memorystream` and response to download the file.
If I do it one by one as below, everything works fine.

```
        var phraseinvoice = new Phrase();
        phraseinvoice.Add(new Chunk("Invoice to:", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 12)));              

        Invoicetable.AddCell(phraseinvoice);
        phraseinvoice = new Phrase();
        phraseinvoice.Add(new Chunk("BCD Meetings & Events Asia Pacific", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 12)));
        PdfPCell inheader = new PdfPCell(phraseinvoice);
        inheader.PaddingBottom = 4;
        inheader.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        inheader.FixedHeight=20f;
        Invoicetable.AddCell(inheader);
```

If I put them inside a array and read from a for loop the PDF will not show any text.

```
 string[] tbText = {" ","Pte.Ltd"," ", "20 Anson Road, #06-01"," ", "Twenty Anson 079912","",
                "Singapore"," "," ","Tel", "1234567", "Fax","123"," "," ","Delivery to:", "BCD Meetings & Events Asia Pacific"," ",
            "Pte,Ltd"," ","20 Anson Road, #06-01"," ", "Twenty Anson 079912"," ","Singapore"};

  Invoicetable.AddCell(inheader);
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
      var inputstring = tbText[i];
      phraseinvoice = new Phrase();
      phraseinvoice.Add(new Chunk(inputstring, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 12)));
      PdfPCell cellbox = new PdfPCell(phraseinvoice);
      cellbox = new PdfPCell(phraseinvoice);
      cellbox.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
      cellbox.Padding= -4;
      Invoicetable.AddCell(cellbox);
  }
```

You can see the differences between first image after -4 padding and second image without padding
[image: before padding]

[image: after padding]

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: There is no error.Just empty output.if i use a loop.If i hard code using same code. it will works

Comment: can it be that you getting cells one on each other?

Comment: could you please debug step over through this code? I think there should an exception. Is your code in try-catch block?

Comment: The behavior that is shown is normal. No exception should be thrown. The problem is caused by setting the `FixedHeight` to a value that is smaller than the height needed to add content. **As documented,** that causes the content to disappear. This is **a necessary feature** for people who **deliberately** want to clip content that doesn't fit a cell.

Comment: Yea.that is the problem.i didnt knew that too. minimum size for font 12 is 20. and 20 is too huge for the spacing in between. i use padding instead. see updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `Phrase` with text in a 12pt font, but you are limiting the height of the cell to 10pt. That explains why nothing is shown.

Change your code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    var inputstring = tbText[i];
    phraseinvoice = new Phrase(inputstring,
        FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 12)));
    PdfPCell cellbox = new PdfPCell(phraseinvoice);
    cellbox.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    cellbox.FixedHeight = 20f;
    Invoicetable.AddCell(cellbox);
}
```

20 user units should be sufficient to show text in a 12pt font.

**Update:**

Another option would be to reduce the font size, for instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    var inputstring = tbText[i];
    phraseinvoice = new Phrase(inputstring,
        FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 8)));
    PdfPCell cellbox = new PdfPCell(phraseinvoice);
    cellbox.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    cellbox.FixedHeight = 15f;
    Invoicetable.AddCell(cellbox);
}
```

But there's more: the height needed by a `Phrase` in a `PdfPCell` depends on:

- The font size,
- The leading,
- The ascender and descender of the font.

For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    var inputstring = tbText[i];
    phraseinvoice = new Phrase(inputstring,
        FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 12)));
    PdfPCell cellbox = new PdfPCell(phraseinvoice);
    cellbox.Leading = 14;
    cellbox.UseAscender = true;
    cellbox.UseDescender = true;
    cellbox.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    cellbox.FixedHeight = 18f;
    Invoicetable.AddCell(cellbox);
}
```

Note how we reduced the `Leading` from the default (1.5 times the font size) to `14`, and how we told the `cellBox` to take the *ascender* and *descender* into account.

Comment: HI, you are right.if the height is too small. the text will not appear.i set from 10-18 all does not appear.20f is the minimium i guess. and 20 is too big for me. i guess i have to hard code every sentence for the Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to add a string as a pdfpcell

> var inputstring = tbText[i];

Invoicetable.AddCell(inputstring);

tbText is a string array

Comment: tbText is array and tbText[index] is array item.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this loop? If the text is fixed you could use a paragraph element with a few newlines (\n)

Comment: to loop the the text as in future the text will be from database query instead. and to reduce repeated code for writing the same thing